# Skipping optional scanf parameters

Tags: c, scanf

I'm working on an assignment for class.
It's about a base number converter. The way it works is the following, example: `convert 11010 2 16` where `11010` is the number to converted, `2` is the original base number and `16` is the goal base number.

But I also want instead of the input number, additional options like `-h` for help, etc.
And if so, I want the base number inputs to be disregarded from even being inputed (the `2` and the `16` to be skipped).

Is it possible with C?

Comment: Are the values provided as command-line arguments, or by input through e.g. `scanf`?

Comment: The professor hoped for command-line arguments but this is a new class for me and I don't know how. He didn't teach it but expect us to look it up and learn it online.

Comment: Then haven't you seen the `main` function take arguments anywhere? Typically like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`? Haven't you ever wondered what these `argc` and `argv` arguments might be? And there are several thousands of tutorials on how to handle command-line arguments in C programs.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding some of the input arguments when certain options are presented is fairly common and certainly doable.  Parse all of your input arguments *before* you do anything with any of them.  Check for your most important options first (in your case, '`-h`').  If it was given, act on it and ignore that the others even existed.  Specifying the "help" parameter for a program generally just `printf`'s a block of text and then immediately exits.

If you're using command-line parameters, this is as easy as iterating through `argv`.  If you're getting input from the console, then you'll need to either read and process input one character at a time (`getchar` plus a state machine), or read the entire line as one string and parse it into an array of individual parameters (essentially reinventing `argv`).